# jquery autocomplete is not working using ajax call

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to create a search box to select country using autocomplete, but facing some issue. I am using flask to get the josn data holding country information.

json file

```
country_lis = [
    {
        "label": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "label": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "label": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "label": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
        "label": "Andorra"
    }]
```

flask route :

```
@app.route('/auto_search_country', methods=['GET'])
def auto_search_country():
    return jsonify(country_lis)
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var country_list;
    $("#country-search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            req=$.ajax({
                url : '/auto_search_country',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            req.done(function(response) {
                country_list = response;
            });
            response(country_list);
        },
        select: function( event, ui ){
        }
        });
});
```

when I type letter its giving me the entire the country list.
Note : if I put the country list in script,  its working properly.

working jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var country_list = [
    {
        "label": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "label": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "label": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "label": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
        "label": "Andorra"
    }]
;
    $("#country-search").autocomplete({
        source:country_list,
        select: function( event, ui ){
        }
        });
});
```